# Why does this code work in a stand-alone page but when used with a Master Page it fails with: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

I have a very simple page which works well - until I drop the code in to a new page which is using a Master Page. I then get the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

My simple (stand-alone) working page is:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="emaillookuptest.aspx.vb" Inherits="emaillookuptest" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="LoginDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:customer_support_devConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:customer_support_devConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [id_staff], [semail] FROM [staff] WHERE ([semail] = ?)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:FormParameter FormField="TextBoxEmailAddress" Name="semail" 
                    Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <p>
            Email Address:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmailAddress" runat="server" MaxLength="100" 
                Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
            <br />
        <asp:Label ID="LabelLoginResults" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the code behind:

```
    Partial Class emaillookuptest
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click

            Dim dv As New Data.DataView
            dv = LoginDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)

            Dim c As Integer = dv.Count.ToString()
            If c <> 0 Then
                LabelLoginResults.Text = "Staff ID: " & dv.Table.Rows(0)("id_staff").ToString()
            Else
                LabelLoginResults.Text = "That email address was not found"
            End If

        End Sub
    End Class
```

As you can see, straight forward enough.

However, as soon as I try and use this code with an existing Master Page, I'm presented with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line:

```
    Dim c As Integer = dv.Count.ToString()
```

The only possible cause that I can see for this is within the master page I have the following:

```
    Dim dv As New Data.DataView
    dv = MyLanguageDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    LitSiteFooterCopyright.Text = dv.Table.Rows(0)("SiteFooterCopyright").ToString()
```

As you can see, I am referecing two different data sources ('LoginDataSource' in my new page and 'MyLanguageDataSource' in my Master Page).

Is the issue because I am using either 'dv' or 'Data.DataView' or 'DataSourceSelectArguments' twice? Once within the master page and once again in my new emaillookuptest.aspx page?

If so, suggestions for either a workaround or the correct way to do this would be welcomed :)

Update: If I remove ALL the code behind from the Master Page, I still get the same error. This just confuses me even more now as the code works perfectly on it's own, yet if I drop it in to an empty Master Page arrangement I get the same error at line: Dim c As Integer = dv.Count.ToString()

Comment: Confirmed, I just created a brand new blank Master Page, then copied my code in to a brand new .aspx page which uses the new/blank Master Page, same error!

Comment: which line is the error called on, it usually in the error page

Comment: Error is on Line 9: Dim c As Integer = dv.Count.ToString()

Comment: So the question now should be "why does this code work in a stand-alone page and fail when used with a Master Page"?

Comment: does `LoginDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)` return anything?

Comment: If I enter an email address which exists in the DB then the id_staff value is returned, yes.

Comment: Also: `Dim dv = *New* Data.DataView` is an instantiation of an object which you are immediately overwriting.  `Dim dv as Data.DataView` should suffice

Comment: I removed the word "New" as suggested, thanks for the tip. Alas no change though, the original error still stands, Line 9: Dim c As Integer = dv.Count.ToString()

Comment: so on the stand-alone page you login with a valid email, dv is Not Nothing; but if you login with the same email on the Master/Child page setup, dv is Nothing? or does it have an object?

Comment: Confirmed that on the stand-alone page when entering a valid email then dv is Not Nothing. Also when using the Master/Child dv is also Not Nothing (same code, same connection, same form value, etc)

Comment: and in the debugger, for both, dv.Count > 0?

Comment: Interesting... If I add a breakpoint in the same place on both (at the Line 9 Dim c As Integer = dv.Count.ToString etc) then on the working stand-alone page, dv = System.Data.DataView (id_staff = 236) - but on the Master/Child combo, dv = Nothing... What on Earth would cause that to happen!?

Comment: ok, that's more like it...that's what I was expecting when i asked about dv being nothing.

Comment: With this in mind, would you therefore know why it works stand alone and why it fails when inserted in to a Master page?? (thanks for the help so far by the way!)

Comment: is the child page trying to make use of a master page variable?

Comment: Nope, it's a brand new and blank Master page (created in VS2010 if that makes a difference)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31273/discussion-between-fnostro-and-rich)